# Is there a site specializing in animal behavior?

Tags: discussion

Amimal behavior as an on-topic subject for TGO has been discussed several times.  The conculsion seems to be that it is on topic, and some animal behavior questions have received good answers in the past. However, there hasn't been much interest in my recent two animal behavior questions, and less expertise than interest evinced. See [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/21604/why-would-a-polar-bear-or-other-top-predator-give-away-his-kill-as-opposed-to-m)  and this [other question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/29154/what-if-any-is-the-empirical-evidence-for-ravens-being-a-helpful-to-humans-o)

I have looked at Biology as a possible host for animal behavior, and Biology has an animal behavior tag, but with with zero questions.

Pets is not a good fit, because I am asking about the behavior of wild animals.

So, my question:

**Is there an existing site on SE that with interest and expertise in the behavior of wild animals?**

**OR:  How can I modify these questions to better fit the interests and expertise on TGO?**

Comment: I guess thats unintended but both the links to questions are same.

Comment: Its a personal opinion, hence the comment here -- The question doesn't need alterations to fit well in the interests of The Great Outdoors. Its just that it attracted less (to the point) answers/responses because the question is valid but about a very specific/uncommon habit of a wild animal. I believe even if the question doesn't yield precise and multiple answers, its not necessarily a bad question. I liked the question for how it is detailed, and what it is about. Its just that sadly I don't know much about it, and that could be the case with many of the users here.